# How to learn maximum id on json with java/android?

Tags: java, android, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to get max id in json page.Because I want to notify each new record.I have a example but I dont understand how to learn max_id on twitter.I have services such as:

```
    {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Sap Title",
            "content": "New Content",
            "date": "2014-07-04 11:02:22",
            "confirm": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "sap title2",
            "content": "new content 2",
            "date": "2014-07-04 03:21:08",
            "confirm": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "sap title 3",
            "content": "new Content 3",
            "date": "2014-07-04 03:29:26",
            "confirm": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "sap title4",
            "content": "new content 4",
            "date": "2014-07-09 01:13:50",
            "confirm": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I found a example for twitter.like:

```
private String getMaxID() {
    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return sp.getString("MaxID", "");
}

private void setMaxID(String maxID) {
    if (maxID != null) {
        final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("MaxID", maxID);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

private Boolean newTweet() {
    Boolean result = false;
    final String oldMaxID = getMaxID();
    String newMaxID = oldMaxID;

    HttpClient httpClient;
    HttpGet getMethod;
    HttpResponse response;
    InputStream responseStream;
    try {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        getMethod = new HttpGet(
                "http://localhost/services/sap/getsaplist.php");
        response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);
        responseStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        final StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder();
        final char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(responseStream, "UTF-8");
        int charCount;
        while ((charCount = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            dataString.append(buffer, 0, charCount);
        }

        final JSONObject data = new JSONObject(dataString.toString());

        if (data.has("max_id_str")) {
            newMaxID = data.getString("max_id_str");

            if (!newMaxID.equals(oldMaxID)) {
                setMaxID(newMaxID);
                result = true;
            }
        }

    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        // Do something with the error in production code
        Log.d(TAG, "ERROR");
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Close out the response stream and any open connections in
        // production code
    }

    return result;
}
```

full example-->[this](https://github.com/Red-Folder/phonegap-samples/tree/master/2.0.0/TwitterExample)

How can I fetch new record like twitter example? thanks

Comment: In your example here `max_id` is 4?

Comment: get size/length of your 'items'?

Comment: yeah max_id = 4 in my json.and if add new record,max_id=5 and old_max_id=4 etc. how can I do that like twitter example?

Comment: I read this json on web service. (http://localhost/services/sap/getsaplist.php) so can you give me a solution with this in mind?